# UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform> from CGAffineTransform

Tags: swift, pointers, unsafe-pointers

I'm trying to create a CGPath in Swift. I'm using `CGPathCreateWithRect(rect, transformPointer)`.

How can I get an `UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform>` from a `CGAffineTransform`? I've tried this:

```
    let transform : CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    let transformPointer : UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform> = UnsafePointer(transform)
```

I've also tried this:

```
    let transform : CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    let transformPointer : UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform> = &transform
```

but Swift complains about a `'&' with non-inout argument of type...`. I've also tried passing `&transform` directly into `CGPathCreateWithRect` but that stops with same error.

When I pass in `transform` directly, Swift "Cannot convert value of type 'CGAffineTransform' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer'".

What's going on, and how can make this work with Swift 2.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Martin R provides the best answer,  but as an alternative, I like to use my unsafe mutable pointers this way, in case you need to alter the actual pointer in the future

```
let path = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&transform)
{
  CGPathCreateWithRect(CGRect(...), UnsafeMutablePointer($0))
}
```

Comment: You don't need a *mutable* pointer and you don't need the pointer cast, so it can be shortened to `withUnsafePointer(&transform) { CGPathCreateWithRect(CGRect(), $0) }`. – I am fairly sure that CGPathCreateWithRect() *copies* the data and does not keep the pointer. Otherwise it would be unusable in C where you can pass the address of a (local) array to that function.

Comment: That is true,  I am not 100% familiar with CGPathCreateWithRect,  I was just going off of memory on how I deal with the unsafe pointers in various situations

Comment: Why is this the answer?  I would prefer to use Martin R way first,  he should get full credit for the answer,  I was just pointing out a different way for unsafe mutable pointers in case people come across that problem

Answer (score 18):

> I've also tried passing &transform directly into CGPathCreateWithRect ...

You were almost there. `transform` needs to be a *variable*
in order to pass it as an inout argument with `&`:

```
var transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
let path = CGPathCreateWithRect(CGRect(...), &transform)
```

For more information, see ["Interacting with C APIs"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html)
in the "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" documentation.

---

In **Swift 3** this would be

```
var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
let path = CGPath(rect: rect, transform: &transform)
```

or, for the identity transform, just

```
let path = CGPath(rect: rect, transform: nil)
```

Comment: In the latest Swift/Xcode this `var transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
` generates this error: CGAffineTransformIdentity is unavailable in Swift

Comment: The second one, with nil, is food to my eyes, a rainbow in my ears and music on my tongue!

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! Syntax in Swift 5 for this is nice, btw: `path.copy(using: &transform)` - very intuitive.