# Swift: understanding pointers

Tags: swift, pointers

I'm trying to create a CoreGraphics Context using the following MacOS Quartz API:

```swift
CGContext.init?(_ url: CFURL, 
                mediaBox: UnsafePointer<CGRect>?, 
                _ auxiliaryInfo: CFDictionary?)
```

, but I'm having trouble with the concept of pointers. I can initiate the context thus:

```
var mypointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGRect>!
mypointer.pointee = myCGRectangle
var writeContext = CGContext.init(outURL, mediaBox: mypointer, nil)
```

But it says that `pointee` is a get-only property. I've tried:

```
var mypointer: UnsafePointer<CGRect>! = UnsafePointer(myCGRectangle)
```

, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342864/unsafepointercgaffinetransform-from-cgaffinetransform), but I get `cannot convert CGRect to expected type`, amongst other errors.

I have looked at several other questions here about pointers, but I can't find anything useful within them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass a reference to your `myCGRectangle` variable, this will create the needed `UnsafeMutablePointer`:

```swift
var writeContext = CGContext(outURL, mediaBox: &myCGRectangle, nil)
```

Make sure the rectangle variable is declared as `var`, otherwise the `&` won't work.

More details can be found on [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/manual_memory_management/calling_functions_with_pointer_parameters) excellent Apple documentation page about passing pointers to functions that require ones.

Comment: Thanks. Google had failed me for that Apple page. Don't see why the variable needs to be var, given that it's not actually changing, but there we are.

Comment: @benwiggy it needs to be a `var` as you're passing a pointer to that storage, a pointer that can be freely modified by the function you're calling.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you do not just create a variable of type `UnsafeMutablePointer<CGRect>` and pass it to the `init(_:mediaBox:_:)`. You rather pass a rectangle for which PDF will be displayed, e.g.

```
var mediaBox = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 500)
...
var writeContext = CGContext(outURL, mediaBox: &mediaBox, nil)
```

(even that is a simplification, as it creates a rectangle directly. Usually you have some rectangle of the view you want to display PDF in, so you will be passing that rectangle.)

You are also allowed to pass `nil` to the `init(_:mediaBox:_:)`. In which case, as docs say:

> If you pass NULL, CGPDFContextCreateWithURL uses a default page size of 8.5 by 11 inches (612 by 792 points).

So if that rectangle fits your needs, just pass `nil` (simpler).

Comment: Sadly, I need the size to be adjustable. Thanks.

Comment: @benwiggy the size is always adjustable: here you only provide a default size. When you call `beginPage(mediaBox` you can always adjust it

Comment: Yes, but beginPDFPage wants a pointer to a box too!

Comment: @benwiggy yes, and this is where you typically provide an actual frame you want to display PDF in. The initialization of `CGContext` is considered expensive, so you init it once (and can specify `nil` for frame - or something else, as you want), but then usually by the time you call `beginPage` you actually have a box to display in (with correct dimensions, which may not be available when you init `CGContext`. So this is where you pass your actual box, and as I said, you don't typically create it, but take existing frame of the view to display in

Comment: When you say "expensive", do you mean time or memory? I'm creating a command line tool for manipulating PDF files, so no views or frames! But I already know the size at init time.